# Performance issues in SSRS? - Filtering measures

Tags: performance, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I am working on a report that I had no problems executing until I added two extra measures to my dataset. When I tried to preview my report it just kept loading and loading...

Here is a snapshot of the dataset. The measures that I am interested in here are `Date of 2:nd markdown` and `Date of 3:rd markdown`

[image]

Here's a snapshot of the dataset filter. Nothing fancy, just `[Date_of_2_nd_markdown] > 20120101`. I only want to retrieve articles that have been lowered twice and this should filter out the 0's

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How many values are you returning?

Comment: It is a large cube (article information) so I will be filtering through a lot of data.

Comment: I think your problem is that your parameters return too many rows. I would try to filter on a week or month rather than date. If you do need dates then limit your dates to a few months.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have also tried using a similar measure called [Week_of_2_nd_markdown] with a filter, however this did not help. Even when I tried filtering from 20150101 is was extremely slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution! My dataset was filtering through a lot of rows and the best way to speed this up was by using an MDX query to retrieve and filter through the data directly in the Query Designer.

I do not know why the filtering goes faster here, but this is the query that I used:

```
FILTER([Product].[Article].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Date of 2:nd markdown] > 20120101)
```

I also removed any unnecessary fields that weren't being used in the report.